# Proof Involving Multivariate Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies $\|f(x)\| = 1$. Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \;\; f'(x) \cdot f(x) = 0$.**

I think I understand the intuition. $f$ is basically a function mapping elements in the real numbers to vectors which comprise the unit sphere. The derivative of $f$ at $x$ is a line perpendicular to $f(x)$ and thus their dot product is $0$. I'm stuck on how to actually go about proving this, however.

I know that if we let $f(x) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
a \\
b \\
c \end{array} \right)$ then $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $\|f(x)\| = 1$ implies $\|f(x)\|^2 = f_1^2(x) + f_2^2(x) + f_3^2(x) = 1$, then differentiate with respect to $x$ on both sides.

Comment: I think I got it (smile). Thanks a lot.